# Where are consumer groups list stored in recent Kafka version?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

Apparently, in earlier kafka version, the list of consumers for a certain consumer group was stored in zookeeper.
Where is this information stored for latest kafka release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.10, the list of Consumer Groups are stored in the `__consumer_offsets` topic.

That topic contains both the committed offsets and the groups metadata (group.id, members, generation, leader, ...). Groups are stored using `GroupMetadataMessage` messages (Offsets use `OffsetsMessage`).

You can dump the groups metadata using the GroupMetadataMessageFormatter. For example:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$GroupMetadataMessageFormatter" \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic __consumer_offsets
```

Note that this is a compacted topic, so to get the list of groups, you would need to "materialize" all entries. This is what brokers do when you use the [`listConsumerGroups()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listConsumerGroups--) API

Comment: what do u mean by materialize entries? @Mickael

Comment: The topic compacted, that means you need to process all entries to compute the final state. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Answer (score 1):

Consumer groups are still available in Zookeeper. Their offsets are stored in Kafka since 0.9 "high level" consumer